# Imported classes are prefixed in Client Library

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In Python I'm creating backend for my Android app. My code is too big so I broke it to 2 files with functions and one with shared classes (shared_classes.py) which inherit from messages.Message.

When I generate client library, all classes get prefixed with name of the python file I stored them in (they look like: SharedClassesExampleName.java).

**Is it possible to force endpointscfg.py to stop generating library with prefixed python classes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api) page (in step no. 4)

*The "package=" line is used by the underlying ProtoRpc when creating names for the ProtoRPC messages you create. This package name will show up as a prefix to your message class names in the discovery doc and client libraries.*

So you if you encounter this problem just add package=' ' (empty value) and your classes will not be prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

customize the API method name with

```
@endpoints.method(name='subject.action')
```

and API class with

```
name = "appname"
```

your API will be accessible at

```
gapi.client.appname.subject.action()
```

check details at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api